# Label Not Showing Progress Bar % VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

I am trying to get a Label to show the % of the Progress bar in a Windows Form using VB.Net 2019 but for some reason, the label is not updating.

If I substitute the Label for the Forms text then it works but I cant see why using the Label will not work.

I must be missing something obvious but I cannot see what!

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ProgressBar.Visible = True
    For i As Integer = 0 To 10
        Dim percent As Integer = i * 10
        ProgressBar.Value = percent
        Label1.Text = percent & "%" '<-- This does not show the %
        Me.Text = percent & "%" '<-- This does show the %
        Thread.Sleep(100)
    Next
    ProgressBar.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing the label did the trick.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ProgressBar.Visible = True
    For i As Integer = 0 To 10
        Dim percent As Integer = i * 10
        ProgressBar.Value = percent
        Label1.Text = percent & "%"
        Label1.Refresh() '<--This updated the Label
        Thread.Sleep(100)
    Next
    ProgressBar.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Task.Delay

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ProgressBar.Visible = True
    For i As Integer = 0 To 10
        Dim percent As Integer = i * 10
        ProgressBar.Value = percent
        Label1.Text = percent & "%"
        Await Task.Delay(500)
    Next
    ProgressBar.Visible = False
End Sub
```